# узнать id фото из сообщения и добавить в массив?

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

у меня есть бот, который выдает рандомно одну фотку из списка посредством id (просто берет ее из вк и кидает в сообщении)

В общем, как я могу знать id фото которое боту прислали в лс, и добавить его в массив(список)?

прошерстил очень много сайтов и документаций, но конкретного ответа и примера кода попросту нет

я банально не знаю с чего начать писать и как

(читал документацию от вк, насчет getbyid, photos и пр. но исчерпывающего ответа так и не нашел)

есть ли у кого ссылка на документацию вот прям уже для чайников? чтобы и объяснение и пример кода

p.s. я не понимаю почему в самих документациях от вк нету примера кода, ведь даже зная теорию, я знаю как это все и куда применить (на вк гитхаб тоже лазил, там только .net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду, вы отправили фотографию в диалог и хотите вычленить из неё айдишник фотки? Сначала получите данные отправленного сообщения через метод https://vk.com/dev/messages.getById. Когда используете метод messages.send, вам возвращается идентификатор сообщения, который вы можете вставить в параметр метода messages.getById. Выполнив запрос на получение информации, вам придёт ответ что-то типо:

```
{
"response": {
"count": 1,
"items": [{
"date": 1609530497,
"from_id": 305824767,
"id": 4515901,
"out": 1,
"peer_id": 2000001182,
"text": "ывыуаыв",
"conversation_message_id": 101,
"fwd_messages": [{
"date": 1609432772,
"from_id": 305824767,
"text": "Присылаю фотки",
"attachments": [{
"type": "photo",
"photo": {
"album_id": -3,
"date": 1609345866,
"id": 457168982,
"owner_id": 305324767,
"has_tags": false,
"access_key": "d0fe95694df7989efb"}]}}
```

Следовательно, извлечь нужно ['response']['items'][0]['attachments'][0]["photo"]["id"]

Comment: ситуация такая, боту в лс кидают картинку, а мне просто через бота нужно узнать айдишник фотки, и просто сохранить

я нигде не смог найти конкретного ответа на вопрос, как определить есть ли вложение в сообщении, и если есть то просто вытащить его айди и сохранить

как оговорился ранее, в документации вк попросту нет конкретного примера использования этого, я сижу весь день уже туплю и все никак.

большинство думает что раз я прошу помощь, то я прошу написать код за меня

возникает лишь один вопрос, а что делать если даже в документации нет примера использования?

не пойму почему так

Comment: Смотрите, ответ сервера приходит в виде {'response': {"items": [{'attachments':[] }] }}. Если вложений нет то 'attachments' равно пустому массиву. Допустим, ответ сервера в переменной r. Проверить наличие вложений это if r['response']['items'][0]['attachments'] == [].

Comment: Следовательно, если картинка есть, извлекается r['response']['items'][0]['attachments'][0]["photo"]["id"]

Comment: Ваша проблема в чём заключается? Вы не можете обработать JSON структуру, не можете сделать POST запрос к методу VK API или совсем запутались в VK API методах?

Comment: скорее последнее, потому что за сегодня прочитал слишком много, и возможно что-то было из этого лишним.

Спасибо вам за ответ и проявленную адекватность, я перечитаю несколько раз ваш ответ, может до меня дойдет что я делаю не так

Comment: все, я понял что как куда и почему, спасибо больше за разъяснение 
просто нужно было выспаться)